# "Add contact" with non-empty fields

Tags: blackberry, contacts

On BlackBerry I want to display an "Add contact" dialog with some fields populated.

I supposed the following code would work:

```
    BlackBerryContact contact = (BlackBerryContact) mContactList.createContact();
    populateSomeFields (contact);
    AddressBookArguments args = new AddressBookArguments(
            AddressBookArguments.ARG_NEW, contact);
    Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_ADDRESSBOOK, args);
```

but no way.

If I `Invoke` with ARG_NEW a completely EMPTY fields are displayed. If I `Invoke` with ARG_COMPOSE an IllegalArgumentException is thrown.

Is there any way I can display "Add contact" with some fields filled in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is no way to do just I want. But there is a nice crutch: commit contact (i.e. add it to phonebook) and then call Invoke with ARG_VIEW.

After that, user can press "edit" or "delete" from the menu.